# A trigonometric integral with sin(cos(x)) in exponent

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Evaluate:
$$\int_0^{\pi} x\csc^{\sin(\cos x)}(x)\,dx$$

---

I honestly don't know how to deal with this case. If I apply the property $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,dx$, I get:
$$\int_0^{\pi} (\pi-x) \frac{1}{(\sin x)^{-\sin(\cos x)}}\,dx$$
but I don't think this is going to help.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a tough integral.  Where does this come from?

Comment: I got it from one of the problem solving website and this problem was a user-shared problem. Its been months and there isn't a single solution to this problem yet. I finally decided to post it on Math.SE. I doubt this has got a nice solution but since I am no expert, I would like to know the opinion of members here.

Comment: The second line should be
$$
\int_0^{\pi} (\pi-x)\csc^{-\sin(\cos x)}(x)\,dx.
$$
It's still difficult anyway. :P

Comment: Woops! I will edit that. :D

Comment: The integrand function is not well defined for real numbers $x$, as the base function takes on negative values in $[0, \pi]$ and the exponent takes on non-integer values.

Comment: @SammyBlack: I am not sure if I understood you. Do you mean $\csc (x)$ takes negative values in $[0,\pi]$? I doubt it.

Comment: You can rewrite the exponential expression to see this more clearly:  $x \csc^{\sin( \cos x )}(x) = x \left[ \csc(x) \right]^{\sin( \cos x )} = x \exp \left[ \sin( \cos x ) \ln ( \csc x ) \right]$.

Comment: Oh!  Of course.  My mistake.  Hmmm.

Comment: In searching for a symmetry (which might make the integral identically $0$), I stumbled upon the functional equation $f(x) \cdot f(\pi - x) = x \cdot (\pi - x)$, but I can't find much use for it.

Comment: Yes, it isn't zero. W|A gives 3.99052. You can look at some of the possible closed forms to this numerical answer here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3.99052 .

Comment: I dropped a high precision result into the Inverse Symbolic Calculator at http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au and came up with nothing.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032284/evaluating-int-0-pi-fracx-sin-x-sin-cos-xdx

Comment: Actually this question was posted before the linked one. It is active now.