# Evaluating $\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{(\sin x)^{\sin (\cos x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Evaluate   $$\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{(\sin x)^{\sin (\cos x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

I tried using by parts and complex numbers along with series expansion but I was unable to find the answer.
Please Help!

Comment: Why would this have a closed form? The limits are not very natural for the integrand.

Comment: @user111187 - I assume the limits are to ensure the integral is defined, as if $\sin x$ is negative, the denominator is undefined.

Comment: Finding a closed form for the antiderivative seems (at least to me) to be a dream.

Comment: Just for hee-haws, it turns out that $$\frac{\cos{x}}{(\sin{x})^{\sin{\cos{x}}}}$$ has an antiderivative in closed form.

Comment: @RonGordon. Please, tell more and show us. I stop my dream and I am awake. How did you get an answer ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I messed around in Mathematica.  Just guessing around, that's all.  I was as surprised as you.  The result is $$\frac{\sin ^{1-\sin (\cos (x))}(x)}{1-\sin (\cos (x))}$$

Comment: @RonGordon. Moreover, it is so simple expression ! How did you think about $\cos(x)$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I spend my days just thinking about cosines.  Every problem, I ask: How can I put a cosine into it?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: OK, bad news...I checked the result in Mathematica and it does not return the original integrand as far as I can tell.  I maybe uncovered a Mathematica bug.  More proof to not trust a machine.

Comment: @RonGordon. Using your result, the integral should be $0$ while numerical integration gives $5.66895$ ! Good catch and enjoy with cosine ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: yes, I should take my own advice and check Mathematica results before posting.  Sigh

Comment: The one equals $$3.9905179137710221001990755970868667785510732535206. $$

Comment: Do you mean in radians?

Comment: I think the “quotient rule” will help. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68505/is-there-a-rule-of-integration-that-corresponds-to-the-quotient-rule

Comment: This function has a part that can be written as $f(x)^{g(x)}$, so I'm pretty sure there isn't an antiderivative in closed form, as @ClaudeLeibovici said.

Comment: maybe $u = \pi - x$

Comment: Here is a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/na02mh3nhs) which explains the bounds. This almost looks like the integral [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xiIsPEqyTqU), but yours is not even or odd.